# delete row in RadGridView By Menu Button

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, dataview

Hello everyone this is my XAML code

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="DatagridKalaieEblaghie" EnableRowVirtualization="True" DataLoaded="DatagridKalaieEblaghie_OnDataLoaded" AddingNewDataItem="DatagridKalaieEblaghie_OnAddingNewDataItem"  SelectionMode="Single"  ClipboardCopyMode="All" ShowGroupPanel="false" CanUserReorderColumns="true"   AutoGenerateColumns="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="135" Width="861" Margin="-8,186,0,0" SelectionChanged="DatagridKalaieEblaghie_OnSelectionChanged" LostFocus="DatagridKalaieEblaghie_OnLostFocus" CanUserDeleteRows="True" >
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewSelectColumn/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="نام کالا"   Width="300" MinWidth="65"    DataMemberBinding="{Binding TitleKala}" CellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewCell}" HeaderTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="سقف اعتبار (ریال)"   Width="250" MinWidth="80" DataMemberBinding="{Binding MablaghSaghfeEtebar, StringFormat=\{0:N0\}}" CellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewCell}" HeaderTextAlignment="Center"/>
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>

    <telerik:RadGridView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem FontFamily="IRANSans" Header="حذف" Click="MenuItem_OnClick">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="../../../../Img/New_ICON/8.Software/delete.png"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
    </telerik:RadGridView.ContextMenu>            
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

and I add row to data grid by add this code to my button click event

```
DatagridKalaieEblaghie.BeginInsert();
```

but how can I remove this by other button like MenuItem ?

Comment: What about CancelEdit method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void MenuItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

                this.DatagridKalaieEblaghie.Items.Remove(DatagridKalaieEblaghie.SelectedItem);


        }
```

I Test It